# SSIS OLE DB destination not mapping correctly

Tags: ssis, odbc, oledb

I am new to SSIS and I need some help here:

I trying to load some data from a ODBC table to a OLE DB destination table: the mapping should be like this:

```
ODBC_source.column1 >> OLEDB_destination.column1;
ODBC_source.column2 >> OLEDB_destination.column2;
ODBC_source.column3 >> OLEDB_destination.column3;
ODBC_source.column4 >> OLEDB_destination.column4;
```

everything works fine until the packages executed, and I queried the destination table I found the mapping became:

```
ODBC_source.column1 >> OLEDB_destination.column2;
ODBC_source.column2 >> OLEDB_destination.column3;
ODBC_source.column3 >> OLEDB_destination.column4;
ODBC_source.column4 >> OLEDB_destination.column1;
```

I checked the mapping tab before executing and it looked fine, but why the mapping mismatched after execution?

Comment: I can't envision a way for what you're describing to happen. The definition in the Column Mapping in the OLE DB Destination is what it is. Is this consistent across the entire table? I've seen situation with flat file sources where a missing/extra delimiter lead to a barber pole striping of column data but that seems unlikely given that it's an ODBC source. Perhaps a screenshot of the OLE DB Destination's column mapping and then put a data viewer before the source and confirm data looks as expected?

Comment: If you experience this while executing the package in the SSISDB catalog, you can add a [data tap](https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2016/12/13/ssis-data-taps/) to confirm the data is in the expected columns before the destination. Otherwise, I'd say you're looking at a support case with Microsoft CSS.